# Can linearization change the time index?

Tags: macroeconomics

In Smets and Wouters 2003, we first have a capital accumulation of the form $K_t= \text{some terms}+ f(I_t)$. 
Later on when linearising the model, they get $\hat K_t= \text{other terms}+ \hat f(I_{t-1})$.

The hat means log deviations from steady-state.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't $f()$ linearized also?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos yes. my typo ;)

Comment: It is still not clear. Is it then $ \hat f(I_{t-1}) = \ln f(I_{t-1}) - \ln f(I_{ss} )$ or is it $\hat f(I_{t-1}) = a(\ln I_{t-1} - \ln I_{ss})$ ?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos it's $\hat f (I_{t-1})=\tau \hat I_{t-1}$, where $\tau$ is a constant.